# Multiple language OCR (Santali+Odia+English) combination is not working with gImageReader

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to scan a Santali book with multiple character (Ol chiki script + English script + Odia script) with gImageReader 3.3.1 (17fa17) which uses Tesseract 4.1.0 but unable to get satisfactory results.

I have tried with English + Odia script are working fine they are giving very good result. But when I use Santali + Odia or English + Santali or Santali + Odia + English the output text becomes Odia, English or Odia and English respectively, instead of showing Ol chiki text in place. I have [a file available for testing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwvin9bqkwc4zol/Santali-Odia-English.tiff?dl=0).

Also, by only using Santali tessdata it transliterate English and Odia words as Ol Chiki script.

When I use "**sat.tessdata**" to scan a normal santali image, it worked well.

Note: Ol chiki is the main writing script of Santali people approved by government of India. I think Ol Chiki is a new script not well supported by many software so the processed image text output always shows boxes, I solved this problem by coping it to the Notepad and saving. Exporting it to pdf is ok, I created editable text from it, no problem. I have created many OCR editable pdf with gImageReader.

My question is how to get combined multiple language output in Santali, Odia and English. Also I want to know why the text output of image when processed giving output for English and Odia but not for Santali or vice versa.

I have tried to train the language, it is taking a lot of time, I have little knowledge on coding. If their is any problem with sat.tessdata then i can take up with learning with Tesseract training.

I have used tessdata of

- Santali - https://github.com/indic-ocr/tessdata/tree/master/sat
- Odia - https://github.com/indic-ocr/tessdata/tree/master/ori
- English - default of gImageReader

Comment: You can try to cut the picture into three columns. Recognize each column with its own language. Collect recognition results into one file.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @AlexAlex I have already tried it worked :-), but if i want to make scan for 20 pages like this then it would be timetaking and that too if i have to create a pdf having all language in one pdf.

Comment: @halfer, Many apology i will never repeat such activity again.

Comment: For combine many pdf files to one, you can use  pdftk with  multibackground options.

Comment: @AlexAlex thanks i have managed to do it by manual hardworking of dowing manual editing each language and create a new pdf and join them.